# How to get averagePowerForChannel of avplayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

How I can get the `averagePowerForChannel` from AVPlayer.
here is my code with AVAudioPlayer but I want to get `averagePowerForChannel` from AVPlayer like this :

```
.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;

.m
- (void)updateMeters
{
    normalizedValue = [self _normalizedPowerLevelFromDecibels:[self.Player averagePowerForChannel:0]];

}
```

Comment: `self.Player` with `AVAudioPlayer *player` does it even compile? Starting method name with "_"? What's your class? Did you call `updateMeters` of `AVAudioPlayer` object?

Comment: no - (void)updateMeters is my custom method

Comment: yes but i'm looking for a way to do this with AVPlayer

Comment: @user3001228 Did you find a way to do this with AVPlayer?

Comment: No there is no way  , marie dm